# Finiteness of center of an algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a connected (affine) algebraic group.

In for example the  Milne's book of algebraic grups we have the theorem

```
  $G$ is semisimple if and only if its Lie algebra is semisimple.
```

In ($\rightarrow$) say:

Suppose $G$ is semisimple and $\mathfrak n$ is an abelian ideal of $\mathfrak g$. Define $H=C_G(\mathfrak n)$ with Lie algebra

$$\mathfrak h=\{x\in\mathfrak g:[x,\mathfrak n]=0\}.$$

Now, $\mathfrak h$ is an ideal because $\mathfrak n$ is an ideal.

Therefore $H^\circ$ is normal in G. Then $Z(H^\circ)$ is normal in $G$.

Because $G$ is semisimple, $Z(H^\circ)$ is finite.

I don't understande why $Z(H^\circ)$ is finite.

Would shall explain me why the finiteness?

Thanks you all.

Comment: It depends on the definition of semisimple group. One of equivalent definitions is that every connected normal subgroup is trivial. So, $Z(H^\circ)$ is closed and has trivial identity component.

Comment: Thanks but, I still do not understand why $Z(H^\circ)$ is a finite group. 
Sorry, would explain more please. 
The definition of semisimple is: $G$ it has no closed connected comuutative normal subroups expect e.

Comment: $Z(H^\circ)^\circ$ is closed, so it is $e$. Thus, $Z(H^\circ)$ has dimension $0$ and finite.

Comment: Thank you! @BorisBilich.